# For Loop for Prime Factors in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to return the factors of a number which are prime numbers in this code. For example, if someone enters in n = 55, they'll get back 5 and 11. I believe I have the first part correct in checking for the factors, but somehow I'm not sure what I'm missing in the second part of checking for prime numbers.

When I run the code for 55, I only get 5 (11 is missing).

Can someone please help review my code and provide feedback?

```
l = []
primefactors = []

def factor(n):
    count = 0

    print 'These are the factors:'
    for num in range(2,n+1):
        if n%num == 0: #checks that it is a factor
            print num #These are the factors
            l.append(num)

    for i in l: 
        if i == 2 : #checks for two
            primefactors.append(i)

        else:
            for x in range(3,i+1,2): #checks for odd numbers
                if  i%x == 0:
                    count += 1
                    if count == 1:
                        primefactors.append(i)


    print "These are the prime factors:"
    print primefactors
```

Comment: Where does `count` come from?

Comment: @user2357112, I accidentally deleted that line when I was deleted the comment lines. I have edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the factors by simply removing all unnecessary stuff, but that will not guaranty, that the number is prime number:

```
l = []
primefactors = []
def factor(n):
    count = 0
    for num in range(2,n+1):
        if n%num == 0 and num != n: #checks that it is a factor
             primefactors.append(num)

    print ("These are the prime factors:")
    print (primefactors)
    del l[:]
    del primefactors[:]
```

Comment: Thanks, but now, if I enter in factor(92), I get [2,23,46]. 46 shouldn't be there. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, 92 is not a prime number, so it has more than 2 factors. 46*2=92. The question is: why there is no 4 - 23*4=92

Comment: 4 is not a prime number (2*2 = 4)

Comment: That is correct. Here is some piece of code to have fun with: 
`def factor(n):
    count = 0
    primefactors = []
    for num in range(2,n+1):
        if n%num == 0 and num != n: #checks that it is a factor
             primefactors.append(num)
    return primefactors

def checker():
    primes = {}
    for i in range(1000):
        fac = factor(i)
        if len(fac) == 0:
            primes[i] = fac
    for k , v in primes.items():
        print (str(k)+" : " + str(v))`

Answer (score 0):

try this one, I added an additional check to see if number is a prime before appending to primefactors list.

```
primefactors = []
def factor(number):
  for i in range(2,int(number//2)+1):
    prime = True
    for j in range(2,int(i**.5)+1):
      if i%j == 0:
        prime = False
        break
    if prime and number%i == 0:
      primefactors.append(i)
  print (primefactors)

factor(92)
factor(55)
```

output:

```
[2, 23]
[2, 23, 5, 11]
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain what the first for loop does? Why is the upper limit of the range (number/2)+1 ?

Comment: prime factors of a number are always in between 2,(number//2)+1.
For example if you 
1) take a number 10, any number greater than 6 can never be its factor. 
2)if number is 11, any  greater than 6 (number//2+1) can never be its factor.
If this answers your question please mark it as answer.